# how can i make the target of a conditional be any of many? search for any of a list of strings rather than just one string? In Haskell

Tags: haskell

In:

```
eval x | "?" `isSuffixOf` x = privmsg (if "what" `isPrefixOf` x then "that would be an ecumenical matter" else "yes")
```

How can I have "what" be any of "what|who|how|why|where|when"?

I know it's not with | like that^, nor is it

```
eval x | "?" `isSuffixOf` x = privmsg (if "what" "who" "how" "why" "where" "when" `isInfixOf` x then "that would be an ecumenical matter" else "yes")
```

but I'm unsure of the logic of whatever syntactical fail I'm hitting upon, so everything else I'm trying are similar stabs in the dark, including searches.

(And how can I phrase this question better than "How can I make the target of a conditional be any of many?"?  (As in, what are the terms I mean, that will better help me understand the situation and better form the search terms?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any):

```
interrogatives = ["what", "who", "how", "why", "where", "when"]

eval x | "?" `isSuffixOf` x = privmsg (
  if any (`isInfixOf` x) interrogatives 
     then "that would be an ecumenical matter" 
     else "yes"
  )
```

Comment: Ah, perfect, & excelent choice of word.  And I see I wasnt as far of in my searches as I thought, with "if any".  oh wait, let me see...     parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Comment: previous line's val     "!leave"               = write "QUIT" ":Exiting" >> io (exitWith ExitSuccess) didnt like being before that.  works with "!leave" after "?" somehow, but not other way around... anyways, that's my problem for another question.  yupyup, seems all good, works as intended, nicely done.  would still love to know more about how to better phrase the question.